# Custom login in bash

Tags: bash, authentication

Is there any way I could execute a script that verifies if user is authorized to log in,after the user has logged in normally, but before he has shell access.

This is to solve a problem that we have with sharing server passwords.

Is it posible?

**What I want to do?**

We are using Yubikeys (OTP Generator). I would like to ask the user trying to log in to generate a new OTP then I, using a web service y created, check for two things:

1) If the owner of the Yubikey is authorized (in a MySql database)

2) If the OTP is valid.

I know I can use yubikeys as Second factor Authentication for Shell access, but I have a centralized system for all the permissions in the company.

**What I have Done**

Edited the ~/.ssh/rc file of the user I was trying to protect. This file makes the validation and then starts the shell only if the user is authorized.

Comment: How do you intend to determine the difference between the account owner and somebody borrowing the account?  (Or is that what you're asking?)

Comment: I updated the question with some more info. I read something about a rc file in the ~/.ssh folder? I´m heading in the good direction?

Comment: You can add extra authentication steps during the login process using `pam` if `ssh` is configured to use `pam`. I believe there are yubikey `pam` modules for this sort of thing even.